npx tsc --init is compulsory in typescript
I prefer installing Typescript locally in a project folder by running:
npm i typescript --save-dev
After installing the Typescript compiler, my tutorial told me to run npx tsc --init to initialize the typescript project and create the tsconfig.json file. However, when I don't run (npx tsc --init), my typescript code still transpiles normally.
Is npx tsc --init compulsory in initial typescript projects? My project is quite tiny. Its purpose is to show the results of the code when I try typescript syntax and concepts.
When manually setting up the reality TS project, is running npx tsc --init compulsory or are other things done to set up the project manually?
I used this article on Google to set up the project for learning TS.


Running npx tsc --init is not strictly compulsory to transpile TypeScript code. The purpose of running npx tsc --init is to generate a tsconfig.json file, which allows you to configure the TypeScript compiler options for your project. If you don't have a tsconfig.json file, TypeScript still can use its default settings to compile your code. This is why your TypeScript code still transpiles normally even without running npx tsc --init.

When setting up a TypeScript project manually, running npx tsc --init is a convenient way to generate a tsconfig.json file with default settings, but it is not the only way. You can manually create a tsconfig.json file as well.


However, having a tsconfig.json file is highly recommended as your project grows, as it gives you more control over the compilation process and helps ensure consistency across different environments.

Thank you, your answer is so clear, thank you so much
